# Tensorflow Object Detection API / ImportError: cannot import name 'keypoint_box_coder_pb2'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

I followed instructions (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) to install the Tensorflow Object Detection
API. I use Anaconda on Windows 10 and all of the steps in the instructions seemed to complete OK.

But when trying to run python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py to test the installation, I get: ImportError: cannot import name 'keypoint_box_coder_pb2'

What am I missing?

> (tensorflow) C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\models\research>python
>   object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       from object_detection.builders import model_builder   File "C:\Users\User\New\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from object_detection.builders import box_coder_builder   File "C:\Users\User\New\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\builders\box_coder_builder.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       from object_detection.protos import box_coder_pb2   File "C:\Users\User\New\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\protos\box_coder_pb2.py",
>   line 17, in  ImportError: cannot import name
>   'keypoint_box_coder_pb2'

Comment: It looks like you have not run `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:\`pwd\`:\`pwd\`/slim `(from tensorflow/models/research folder) in the same terminal before launching the test, have you ? If you've chosen the .bashrc option, you probably need to reload your bshrc filewith  `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. What I did was:

I ran:

```
protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\argmax_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\bipartite_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_predictor.proto .\object_detection\protos\eval.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\grid_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\hyperparams.proto .\object_detection\protos\image_resizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\input_reader.proto .\object_detection\protos\keypoint_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\losses.proto .\object_detection\protos\matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\mean_stddev_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\model.proto .\object_detection\protos\optimizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\pipeline.proto .\object_detection\protos\post_processing.proto .\object_detection\protos\preprocessor.proto .\object_detection\protos\region_similarity_calculator.proto .\object_detection\protos\square_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map.proto .\object_detection\protos\train.proto
```

What was missing was: `.\object_detection\protos\keypoint_box_coder.proto`

Then ran:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Then changed:
`nets` to `research.slim.net` in `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py` and `faster_rcnn_resnet_v1_feature_extractor.py` (in the models folder)

Ran:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

Got:

```
Ran 11 tests in 0.195s
```

OK

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not run

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim     # (from tensorflow/models/research folder)
```

in the same terminal before launching the test, have you ? If you've chosen the .bashrc option, you probably need to reload your bshrc filewith  `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I'm in Windows 10, so I tried to append the tensorflow/models/research/ and slim directories to the PYTHONPATH with set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\models;C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\models\slim
This seems to work, I checked it with:  python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" and got:
['', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\GitHub\\models', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\GitHub\\models\\slim',... ]. But when I try to run model_builder_test.py, I now get: python: can't open file 'object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.